# UML activity diagram combined join and fork nodes

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, activity-diagram, argouml

Is it valid to have the following combined join and fork nodes in a UML activity diagram or is it wrong?

I searched online and in some UML books but I cannot find a clear answer or a similar example.

The idea is to have two actions (1 and 2) that need to be completed and then synchronised before the start of actions 3 and 4.

Should I just introduce a *sync* action between a join and a fork node to be on the safe side?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is valid.

In the UML specifications version 2.5.1 you'll find on page 391

> The functionality of a JoinNode and a ForkNode can be combined by
> using the same node symbol, as illustrated in Figure 15.31. This
> notation maps to a model containing a JoinNode with all the incoming
> ActivityEdges shown in the diagram and one outgoing ActivityEdge to a
> ForkNode that has all the outgoing ActivityEdges shown in the diagram.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if this how you want it done?

[Fork end merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYoqT.jpg)

Comment: @geert, it's been a while since I used/browsed StackOverflow. I noticed that you edited my comment and I wanted to ask you in a private message but the facility is not there. What does the removal of my edit/comment mean? Regards.

Comment: You shouldn't add comments in answers. Answers should only contain Answers, and nothing else. People down/up vote answers based on whether they find the answer useful, and that's it. They are not obligated in any way to justify that vote. A tip for images is to use the image buttons SO provides (or simply paste the image). Another user can then edit your answer and inline the image simply by adding a "!" in front of it. Because you did it another way, this is no longer possible.